# Calling other controller methods from a controller failed in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I want to call upload_controllers methods in admin controller. I've attached my code here. But its not working. Rather its shows `Unable to locate the specified class: Session.php`

```
class Admin_controller extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
          this->load->helper('url');
     }

     function index(){
          require_once(APPPATH.'controllers/uploads_controller.php');
          $testObj = new uploads_Controller();
          $testObj->index();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your controllers should be upper cased. Secondly, if you need to use one same part of code in different controllers (i.e. same method) you should make custom library and load it in controller that is in use. That way you would follow MVC paradigm correctly.

Comment: Thank you. But how to I perform database operations from custom library classes.

Comment: In case you want reusable of DB operations you need model that supports wanted operations so you could call it from different controllers. Just load same model in any controller that require particular results. Libraries (and sometimes helpers) are planned to contain functions/methods you use in controller, but models should contain methods for DB data pulling. Just load what ever better suits your application.